# Сбор данных с открытого Api в режиме реального времени(Nest.js, PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api

Разрабатываю бэкенд для одного ресторана суть в чём:
все данные о ресторане, о блюдах , заказах и многом другом находятся на отдельном сервере (не моём) и получаются через отдельные запросы.
Эти данные я могу стянуть себе и использовать как мне нужно, также я могу изменить статус заказа, поменять что-либо в заказе, но получение данных происходит не в режиме реального времени.
Например, создал клиент заказ на блюдо, допустим, через веб-сервер, данные о заказе идут сначала на сторонний сервер, и только с него я могу забрать данные, сделав на фронте кнопку "обновить".
Есть ли какие-то вариации решения без самостоятельного обновления запроса? Чтобы при создании заказа данные поступали мне сразу? (читал про websoket, но как я понял, он тут не подойдёт)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А ваш сервер и клиентская часть знают друг о друге?

Comment: SwaD, мой сервер пока что работает по такому принципу: забирает данные с стороннего сервера(API) через доступные методы и записывает это всё в БД, и, соответственно, при обращении к моему серверу данные будут идти на фронт, например, для демонстрации времени приготовления блюда и т.д.
p.s. я пока только начинаю работать с API, так что извините, если не понял вопроса :)

Comment: Пользователь создал заказ, вам должен придти "тикет". Далее вы раз в Н времени долбаете стороннее АПИ и при изменении данных отправляете их клиенту. Вебсокет тут как раз вам поможет

Comment: Т.е, пользователь создал заказ, мне приходит уведомление, что заказ с такими-то параметрами создан. Записываю его в БД и с помощью вебсокета отслеживаю изменения данных, обращаясь к сторонней АПИ в определённом интервале?