# Получение данных со стороннего Аpi. Nest + WebSocket

Tags: node.js, postgresql, websocket

Вопрос по работе со связкой Nest + WebSocket.

На текущий момент мне нужно чтобы WebSocket поддерживал постоянное соединение к стороннему API для сбора заказов и записи их в БД.

В API имеется авторизация JWT (токен для этого я генерирую методом с помощью данных, которые мне предоставляет пользователь).

С фронтом это всё пока что не будет связываться(в дальнейшем будет). На текущий момент это всё нужно для анализа и построения стабильной БД.

Вкраце: мне нужно чтобы мой сервер поддерживал постоянное (макс раз в минуту) соединение и вытягивал данные, если они поменялись.

В работе с WebSocket я пока что новичек, так что возникает ряд вопросов по использованию. Многие руководства используют фронт для его работы.

1. Есть ли какие-то полноценные/новые руководства для лучшего понимания?
2. Имеет ли вообще мой способ путь к существованию или есть что-то более простое, нежели использование WebSocket

Comment: Вообще, суть сокета - держать постоянное соединение и обмениваться по нему данными, только не в формате запрос/ответ, а в формате - можно отправить данные, можно получить данные. Каждый участник соединения равноправен и может посылать сообщения в любое время и по своему усмотрению. Если это вопрос продолжение [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477845/), то вам надо настроить сокет как раз между вашим сервером и клиентом

Comment: @SwaD Т.е. мне нужно сделать, чтобы мой сокет самостоятельно ходил в стороннюю АПИ и вытягивал/сравнивал нужные данные и записывал их в мою БД?
Просто немного не понятен контекст: 'вам надо настроить сокет как раз между вашим сервером и клиентом'

Comment: Клиентское приложение должно общаться с вашим сервером через сокет, что бы сервер мог в любой момент времени уведомить клинтское приложение об изменениях. А к стороннему серверу ходите по старому. Вообще сложно давать более точные рекомндации, не понимая, почему ваше клиентское приложение ходит куда то на сторонний сервер, а обновлять информацию надо вам )